# Login form redirection to password change form

Tags: vba, ms-access, authentication

I have the code below in regards to a login page for my access database I'm developing. The code is supposed to stop incorrect logins as well as redirect those whose password is "password" to make a new, more secure password. Unfortunately, when the user enters password, they get access to the navigation form, so the opposite of what was intended. I'm on a time crunch to get this completed so unfortunately I can't research as I normally would. **Please help me identify how to have the password "password" redirect users to the "NewRequestee" form.**

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Dim TempPass As String
Dim ID As Integer

If IsNull(Me.txtusername) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Username into the appropriate field.", vbInformation, "UserName Required"
    Me.txtusername.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtpassword) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a password into the appropriate field.", vbInformation, "Password Required"
    Me.txtpassword.SetFocus
Else
    'process the job
    
    If (IsNull(DLookup("UserName", "Requestees", "UserName='" & Me.txtusername.Value & "'"))) Or _
    (IsNull(DLookup("Password", "Requestees", "Password='" & Me.txtpassword.Value & "'"))) Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect User Name or Password"
    Else
        TempPass = DLookup("password", "Requestees", "UserName='" & Me.txtusername.Value & "'")
        ID = DLookup("RequesteeID", "Requestees", "UserName='" & Me.txtusername.Value & "'")
        DoCmd.Close
        If (TempPass = "Password") Then
            MsgBox "Please update your password to a personalized, secure password.", vbInformation, "New password required!"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "NewRequestee", , , "[RequesteeID] = " & ID
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenForm "RequesteeMainMenu", , , "[RequesteeID]= " & ID
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit: I also have the code down below for Facilities workers to log into; this code works correctly in stopping users whose password is "password" and redirects the user to a password change form. Can someone please help me see the difference between the two that is disallowing the code above to execute properly?

```
Private Sub Command23_Click()
Dim UserLevel As String
Dim TempPass As String
Dim ID As Integer
Dim Status As String

If IsNull(Me.txtusername) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Username into the appropriate field.", vbInformation, "UserName Required"
    Me.txtusername.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtpassword) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a password into the appropriate field.", vbInformation, "Password Required"
    Me.txtpassword.SetFocus
Else
    'process the job
    
    If (IsNull(DLookup("UserName", "AssignedWorkers", "UserName='" & Me.txtusername.Value & "'"))) Or _
    (IsNull(DLookup("Password", "AssignedWorkers", "Password='" & Me.txtpassword.Value & "'"))) Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect User Name or Password"
    Else
        UserLevel = DLookup("Levelaccess", "AssignedWorkers", "Username='" & Me.txtusername.Value & "'")
        TempPass = DLookup("Password", "AssignedWorkers", "Username='" & Me.txtusername.Value & "'")
        ID = DLookup("WorkerID", "AssignedWorkers", "Username='" & Me.txtusername.Value & "'")
        Status = DLookup("Status", "AssignedWorkers", "Username='" & Me.txtusername.Value & "'")
        DoCmd.Close
        If (TempPass = "Password") Then
            MsgBox "Please change default password to a personalized, secure password.", vbInformation, "New password required!"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Facilitiespasswordchange", , , "[WorkerID] = " & ID
        Else
            If (Status = "Inactive") Then
                MsgBox "This staff member has been flagged as inactive. Please contact your systems administrator.", vbInformation, "Inactive Staff"
                DoCmd.OpenForm "FacilitiesLogin"
            Else
                If (Status = "Pending") Then
                MsgBox "This staff member has not been approved by an administrator as Facilities Staff. Please contact your systems administrator.", vbInformation, "Pending Staff"
                DoCmd.OpenForm "FacilitiesLogin"
                Else
                    If UserLevel = "Level_1" Then
                        DoCmd.OpenForm "F1MainMenu", , , "[WorkerID]= " & ID
                    ElseIf UserLevel = "Level_2" Then
                        DoCmd.OpenForm "F2MainMenu", , , "[WorkerID]= " & ID
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Have you step debugged?

Comment: Really need db login? Can't just assume user is valid because they logged in to Windows? Is this designed for a multi-user workstation? How do you want to handle situation where one user leaves db open and another user just walks up and starts using? Are you aware of 'shift-key bypass'? Access isn't really designed to be a secure db (not since Access2003).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not smart enough to figure out how to use the active directory to used as a login method. It is a multi-user station; it's a ticketing method for facilities to field repair requests and such; no PHI involved. I am aware of the shift key bypass; I know there is code to lock that and make it only available to admin, but I'd have to learn it. I understand your critique of the software; it's what I'm stuck with to address this need.

Comment: I don't use the active directory. I do maintain a Users table just because I need to capture user ID to save with some records. I use Environ("USERNAME") to get Windows username and match this to record in Users. If it doesn't exist then user is presented with a form where they input their initials and a new record is created in Users. They never see this 'login' form again. The initials are saved with other records during data entry. Also, I use this to manage what users can do on some forms. Only "admin" user gets certain buttons on some forms. It's not intended to be a secure db.

Comment: But in my case, these are single-user workstations. Again, did you step debug?

Comment: I don't know what that is. The debug message box didn't appear regarding the issue I have, but if you mean implementing the code in "chunks" at a time, no i didn't.

Comment: Google "Access VBA how to debug". Set a breakpoint and step through code to see if it does what is expected. See if variables are populated correctly. Start with https://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/vbadebug2010/debug01.php. Just reading through your code, I am not seeing issue with it.

Comment: Use Windows security as suggested by @June7

Comment: I honestly don't know how to use Windows security to complete this. This code was something i took from multiple login creation videos on youtube. If someone could walk me through the steps it would be greatly appreciated. I want to do the research and have tried many times to get this login form right, but I have a deadline to have this ready for launch on April 1st, and I want to meet that need. As far as the step debug, I could do it but I wouldn't be entirely confident that I could interpret the findings.

Is Environ a separate software? If so, I doubt we have it or would get it.

Comment: I edited my post to include what code I have for Facilities users to log into separately; their code is similar to the first batch of code, only theirs actually works regarding rerouting users to a password change form. Can someone help me fix the first code to behave like the second?

Comment: I have made some progress in understanding what is wrong. My requestee login (the first code) is allowing any passwords entered into the Requestee table as valid regardless of the Username. If the password entered isn't one of the options on the table for all users, then it gets kicked back as incorrect. What work around can I provide to that code to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: I am trying different methods to try to get this login page to work; my previous comment is still valid that any username would be able to login so long as they have entered a password that is on the table. Please help me figure out where my coding went wrong.